# Haskell counting words containing specific characters in strings

Tags: string, haskell, count, words

is it possible to get the number of words which contain a specific character from a string ?

for example: string = "yes no maybe"

it would return 2 if the specific character was 'e'.

I have been trying for hours :(

thanks

Comment: Check the function `elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`. Then you can filter and check the length.

Comment: are you able to show me a working example from the example I gave? i just cant do it :( my head is mess

Comment: @j0rd4nn2 You have to demonstrate that you made some effort towards finding a solution; Stack Overflow isn't a place where you can just ask people to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this (shown as a GHCi session) is:

```
λ> let w = "yes no maybe"
λ> length $ filter (elem 'e') (words w)
2
```

We split the string into words using the `words` function.
Then filter the list of words using `elem` and our chosen character.
Then finally count the number of words that contained the character, using `length`.

Can also be written as:

```
length . filter (elem 'e') $ words w
```

composing the `length` and `filter` functions, then applying the combined function to the list of words.